# Checking for game objects position

Tags: java, validation

I'm making a game where a game object, a squirrel, is trying to evade another object, the terriers. Here is what I have so far:
**Squirrel.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Squirrel implements AnimalInterface {

    //
    // DO NOT MODIFY BELOW 
    //
    private int currentRow;
    private int currentCol;
    private int previousRow = -1;
    private int previousCol = -1;
    private int closestRow;
    private int closestCol;
    private char[][] field;

    // Initializes position and field
    public Squirrel(int row, int col, char[][] field){
        this.currentRow = row;
        this.currentCol = col;
        this.field = field;
    }

    // Getters
    public int getCurrentRow(){ return currentRow; }
    public int getCurrentCol(){ return currentCol; }
    public int getPreviousRow(){ return previousRow; }
    public int getPreviousCol(){ return previousCol; }
    public int getClosestRow(){ return closestRow; }
    public int getClosestCol(){ return closestCol; }
    //
    // DO NOT MODIFY ABOVE 
    //

    // Find closest terrier
    public void findClosest(){
        int rows = 0; int cols = 0;
        //rows = field[0][0]; cols = field[1][0];

         // TO DO: Replace with code to find closest
         closestRow = -1;
         closestCol = -1;

         rows = field.length;
         cols = field[0].length;

         double dist = 0;
         double newDist = 0;

         for(int i = currentRow; i < rows; i++) {
               for(int j =0; j < cols; j++) {
                        //if its 'D' for Terrier
                       if(i != currentRow && j != currentCol && field[i][j] == 'D') {
                           //find Euclidean distance
                           newDist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(currentRow - i, 2)+Math.pow(currentCol - j, 2));
                           if(dist == 0) {
                               dist = newDist;
                               closestRow = i;
                               closestCol = j;
                           } else if(newDist < dist) {
                               dist = newDist;
                               closestRow = i;
                               closestCol = j;
                           }

                       }
               }
            }

            }



    // Move squirrel according to the rules
    public void moveAnimal() {

        eMove move;

        // Store previous position
        previousRow = currentRow;
        previousCol = currentCol;

        // TO DO: replace with code to select move (Step 1)
        move = eMove.RIGHT;


        // TO DO: replace with code to adjust move (Step 2)
        move = move;

        // TO DO: replace with code to make move (Step 3)
        currentCol++;
    }

    //
    // Private Methods, if you need them
    //

}
```

I need to finish these two steps, but I'm not sure how to check for the position of the terrier so I can make the squirrel move in the opposite direction:

STEP 1) Select the move (of type eMove) which is in the exact opposite direction from the closest Terrier. For example, if the Terrier is left on the same row, move right. If the Terrier is below on the same column, move up. If the Terrier is above and right, move down and left. If the Terrier is below and right, move up and left, and so on.

STEP 2) Adjust the selected move (of type eMove) to avoid going off the board, running into a Terrier, or running into another Squirrel by carefully implementing the following behavior (in the order shown). You probably will want implement a private method to see if a particular move is valid.

If you are planning on moving DOWN_LEFT, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move LEFT instead.
If you are planning on moving LEFT, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move UP_LEFT instead.
If you are planning on moving UP_LEFT, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move UP instead.
If you are planning on moving UP, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move UP_RIGHT instead.
If you are planning on moving UP_RIGHT, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move RIGHT instead.
If you are planning on moving RIGHT, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move DOWN_RIGHT instead.
If you are planning on moving DOWN_RIGHT, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move DOWN instead.
If you are planning on moving DOWN, but that move is not valid for one of the reasons above, move DOWN_LEFT instead.
If you get through adjusting the move as specified above, and the move is still not valid, set the move to NO_MOVE and return without updating the position.

If anymore information is needed let me know, thank you!

Comment: Q: Is the a school assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Add setters

```
public void setCurrentRow(int newRow){ currentRow=newRow; }
public void setCurrentCol(int currentCol){ currentCol=newCol; }
```

If the terrier has a higher column location than you, move lower (set the column to a lower value), if it's higher, move lower.  Same for the row.

```
if (mySquirrel.getCurrentCol() > aTerrior.getCurrentColumn())
{
  mySquirrel.setCurrentCol(mySquirrel.getCurrentCol()+1)
}
//...etc (one for < aTerrior and two for the rows)...
```